# Get data when select criteria in other table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, now I want an output of all matches with the season I select in active_season. When I try the query below I get an error. Can someone help me?

```
SELECT * FROM `matches` 
Where season = active_season.season
```

Error :  #1054 - Unknown column 'active_seasons.season' in 'where clause'

```
table matches
id  date        season      team_a  team_b 

1   2015-08-23  2015-2016   yellow  red
2   2015-04-18  2014-2015   green   blue
3   2015-09-04  2015-2016   white   brown
4   2014-02-11  2013-2014   pink    yellow
5   2015-03-19  2014-2015   red brown
6   2015-11-30  2015-2016   blue    pink        
7   2015-05-06  2014-2015   green   white

table active_season
id  season
1   2015-2016
```

Comment: You are introducing the concept of table active_season that was not part of this set of tables : (the from clause or a join). And the db engine is like, huh, where did that come from ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: but whatever you do, if you join, do an **explicit join**. It is like the year 2015

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should error like the way you are doing. What you need to do is perform a `JOIN` operation like

```
SELECT m.* FROM `matches` m
JOIN active_season ac ON m.season = ac.season;
```

(OR) add the table `active_season` in your `FROM` clause like

```
SELECT * FROM `matches`, active_season 
Where season = active_season.season
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a table's fields in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` parts of the query, it has to be in the `FROM` part. Think of `SELECT` as resource delivery part, `WHERE` as filtration part and `FROM` as the resource holding area which provides the required resources for the parts mentioned earlier.

Now when you use multiple tables in the `FROM` part, MySQL returns a product of these table. e.g. If you have following two tables with given rows:

```
table1 (id, title)
------------------
id    title
------------------
1     first
2     second
```

and

```
table2 (id, fk_id, description) // fk_id is foreign key from table1 
-------------------------------------
id    fk_id    description
1     1        d1
2     2        d2
```

And you run this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

You get this result:

```
id    title    id    fk_id    description
-----------------------------------------
1     first    1     1        d1
1     first    2     2        d2
2     second   1     1        d1
2     second   2     2        d2
```

every record of `table1` against every record of `table2` i.e. a product of two tables. To get correct results, you need to specify which record of table1 matches with which record of table2. This can be done using a condition in `WHERE` part or a `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.fk_id
-----------------------------------------
id    title    id    fk_id    description
-----------------------------------------
1     first    1     1        d1
2     second   2     2        d2
```

Same result will be achieved when using a `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.fk_id
-----------------------------------------
id    title    id    fk_id    description
-----------------------------------------
1     first    1     1        d1
2     second   2     2        d2
```

Similarly your problem can be solved by using an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    `matches` a
    JOIN active_season b ON a.season = b.season
WHERE 
    b.season='2015-2016'
```

You can read about MySQL joins in detail here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to also provide some explanations to explain your reasoning and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mac.* 
FROM `matches` mac
JOIN 
       active_season ac 
    ON mac.season = ac.season;
```